# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy', importing in app.py but not subprocess

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Trying my hand at Flask as a prototyping method and encountering some issues.

Basically I have my app.py starting a subprocess (tracking.py) that does all some user tracking.

I have a couple of values that should go to a database every now and again for safekeeping (I did this with a .json before but figured the database would be cleaner).

Those values are all gathered in tracking.py.

Now I'm sure this is a rookie mistake but when I import

`from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`

in tracking.py, I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'.

This seems odd because I have no problem importing it from app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, send_file
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import threading
import atexit
import subprocess
```

and both are in the same venv.

Happy to provide any further info but I assume it's a dumb oversight.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling (making sure I installed with pip3) and looked at the documentation for SQLAlchemy but could find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said basically your subprocess (or tracking.py to be precise) isn't finding the module. Since it's same after reinstalling there's best bet is to check the virtual environment.
You could try something like

```
execute = f"source venv/bin/activate && {file}"
subprocess.run(["/bin/bash", "-c", execute], shell=False)
```

or just output some environmental variable to check if it's indeed running in the venv.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this!
I compared environment variables and they are absolutely identical (printed sys.path and checked the output) I decided to run the code a little differently which circumvented the issue but I am now running into the same issue with pynput which I just added in the subprocess. It's a little frustrating.